# Python application memory profiling not accurate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am profiling Python 3 application and trying to understand where the memory is allocated.

I tried multiple libraries:

1. `pympler`
2. `tracemalloc`

Pymler code:

```
all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
summary.summarize(all_objects)
```

Tracemalloc code:

```
current_snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()

total_size = 0
for stat in current_snapshot.statistics("filename"):
   total_size += stat.size

print(total_size)
```

Both of these tools report over 10 times less memory than Python application actually consumes. The application can consume over 500 MB and I get under 50 MB on the reports.

I am checking memory usage, both, manually and using the function below:

```
mem_usage = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

# resource.getrusage provides memory usage in bytes on OSX but in kilobytes for other platforms
if sys.platform != constants.PLATFORM_MAC:
   mem_usage *= 1024

return mem_usage
```

I call `gc.collect()` prior generating reports in the code.

I used `gc` library to see if the application is leaking any memory but do not see anything significant.

Can someone explain why can I see such a drastic difference?

Comment: Are you checking the application memory usage manually without running the memory profiling code? "Memory leaking" usually not the case, but GC could simply not have ran yet, which would mean a lot of memory waiting to be deallocated, but not deallocated yet.

Comment: I updated the question details with the information.